# wp.customize.previewer.bind: "Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I am trying to follow [this tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/customizer-javascript-apis-the-previewer--cms-27313) on the WordPress Customizer JavaScript API, but I am running into the following snag:

When I try to run this code, I get the following error: 
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined`

```
(function($){

  var customize = wp.customize;

  customize.previewer.bind( 'preview-edit', function( data ) {
     // Some code
  } );

})(jQuery);
```

I am enqueueing the script in my `functions.php` with the following hook:

```
function wf_customize_control_js() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'wf_customizer_control', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/wf-customize.js', array( 'customize-controls', 'jquery' ), null, true );
}
add_action( 'customize_controls_enqueue_scripts', 'wf_customize_control_js' );
```

Comment: try with wrapping your js code into some delaying function, like `set_timeout`, `jQuery(document).ready` and etc.

Comment: Wrapping my code in "$(document).ready(function(){});" fixed it, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering discussion on your question: wrap your function into `jQuery(document).ready` function to prevent your code running earlier than defined `variable` from other js script you're trying to use.